# Temporary redirection of all requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a self updating application - meaning there is a view where user can select an update package, if available, and appliaction will install it(add files, remove files or overwrite existing files). This update can take a while and I'd like to redirect all **new** requests which may come to the application to a website-cannot-be-used-beacuse-there-is-update-in-progress page. My guess is that I cannot redirect requests already in progress, but maybe there is a way to suspend the update till all requests have finished and block incoming ones and start it once they finished. Any tips, please?

Comment: you can use a HttpModule..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

Step 1 : set an environement indicating you are 'updating'
Step 2: Create a route handler

```
public class UpdatingRouteHandler: MvcRouteHandler
{
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext Context)
    {
        //Check if environment var is set to 'updatestate'
        if (  updatestate)
        {
            Context.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "LandingPage";
            Context.RouteData.Values["action"] = "Index"; 
        }
        return base.GetHttpHandler(Context);
    }
}
```

Step 3 : add an MVCRouteHandler to your routing

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Landingpage",
    url: "Landingpage/{id}/{*dummy}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Landingpage", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
).RouteHandler = new UpdatingRouteHandler();
```

It still is MVC so if there is nothing loaded nothing will be shown.

Another path might be to implement Application_BeginRequest() in Global.asax and do some redirecting from there.

Comment: Thanks, that RouteHandle worked the way I want to, and do you know about any way to find out whether there still are any requests being processed?

Comment: Take a look at global.asax and the method protected void Application_BeginRequest(). Maybe that's what you are looking for.